# Google Maps Android SDK - Get features based on user location

Tags: geojson, google-maps, android

I am using Google Maps Android Utility SDK, using GeoJSON features.

I would like to, based on the user Location (which I already have) determine the features that contain this point.

Does Google Maps provide such utility or should I implement by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do quick calculations using the bounding box with:

```
Location location = ...;
GeoJsonFeature feature = ...
LatLng point = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

if (feature.getBoundingBox().contains(point)) {
    // Polygon contains the point
}
```

If you want to use the actual polygon geometry, that's a little more complicated. `PolyUtil.containsLocation(LatLng point, List<LatLng> polygon, boolean geodesic)` returns a true if the polygon contains the point, and false if it does not.

Given a `GeoJsonFeature`, I *believe* (without having tested it myself) you can extract the points from that feature and then pass those points into `PolyUtil.containsLocation()`.

So, for testing actual polygon geometry:

```
Location location = ...;
GeoJsonFeature feature = ...
LatLng point = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

if (feature.getGeometry() instanceof GeoJsonPolygon) {
    GeoJsonPolygon polygon = (GeoJsonPolygon) feature.getGeometry();
    if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(point, polygon.getOuterBoundaryCoordinates(), false) {
        // Polygon contains the point            
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this could potentially work, if the Geometry isn't a MultiPolygon. But what if it is? I understand that doing that check by iterating in all the Polygons of the MultiPolygon would do the trick.